# Realizar esta petición de java en vb.net

Tags: java, vb.net, webservice, soap, vb6

me encuentro consumiendo un servicio soap en el cual tengo este método de ejemplo en java:

```
private static String enviarFactura(EBfelEncabezadofactura objetoFactura) {
    co.com.dis.wsd.soap.InterSoap_Service service=new co.com.dis.wsd.soap.InterSoap_Service();
    co.com.dis.wsd.soap.InterSoap port = service.getInterSoapPort();
    Map<String, Object> req_ctx = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
    req_ctx.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://localhost:8080/WSD/InterSoap?wsdl");
    Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    headers.put("username", Collections.singletonList("TEST"));
    headers.put("password", Collections.singletonList("TEST"));
    headers.put("token", Collections.singletonList("TEST"));
    req_ctx.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);

    return port.enviarFactura(objetoFactura);
}
```

Cuando intento consumir el servicio desde vb.net me ha sido imposible enviar el token como header, de que manera lo podría hacer ?

```
Public Shared Function enviarFactura(ByVal arg0 As eBfelEncabezadofactura) As envioFacturaRespuestaDTO

    Dim service As co.com.dis.wsd.soap.InterSoap = New co.com.dis.wsd.soap.InterSoap()
    Dim myCredentials As System.Net.CredentialCache = New System.Net.CredentialCache()
    Dim netCred As New NetworkCredential("TEST", "TEST")
    myCredentials.Add(New Uri(service.Url), "Basic", netCred)
    service.Credentials = myCredentials

    Return service.enviarFactura(arg0)
End Function
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Debes obtener el `SoapContext`:

```
Dim requestContext As SoapContext = service.RequestSoapContext
```

y despues añadir el token:

```
requestContext.Security.Tokens.Add(userToken)
```

Tienes mas información [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.services2.security.tokens.usernametoken.aspx)

Comment: Hola @Pikoh muchas gracias, me es imposible obtener el RequestSoapContext  de  Dim service As co.com.dis.wsd.soap.InterSoap = New co.com.dis.wsd.soap.InterSoap()  debería cambiar mi petición?